# How to href tel for number like *123#

Tags: html

I made href tel link for *123# number with

```
<a href="tel:*123#">*123#</a>
```

But when I click the link, it only show *123 at the phone. Is there any way to make it show *123# at the phone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works on my phone.

As alternative, try replacing '#' with `&#35;` like so:

```
<a href="tel:*123&#35;">*123&#35;</a>
```

Comment: which phone and browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Xiaomi, maybe it is the phone fault. I will try to use another phone. Thanks!